# Raycast help (using C#)

Tags: raycasting

I have a raycast going upwards from an object which when the player comes in contact with the ray the object changes color.  That works but I want to do it so when you touch the ray a second time, the object gets destroyed and I have no idea how to do that.  I'm using Unity 2d.

Code:  `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyEnemy : MonoBehaviour //Enemy 3
{

```
[SerializeField] Transform Enemy3WayPoint;
private Renderer rend;
private Color colorToTurnTo = Color.blue;



void Start()


{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.enabled = true;
    Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
}
```

private void Update()
    {

```
    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.up, 5);
    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {

        rend.material.color = colorToTurnTo;
       Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hitInfo.point, Color.white);


    }`
```

There may be a bracket or two I forgot to include, it does work when I test it

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: @JoeSewell  I put the code in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to use a variable to keep track of the number of times the ray has been hit by the player.

As for destroying the enemy, you can use the destroy function.
So, something like this:

```
int hitCount = 0; //add a class variable

void Update(){

    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.up, 5);

    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        hitCount++;
    }

    if(hitCount == 1)
    {
        rend.material.color = colorToTurnTo;
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hitInfo.point, Color.white);
    }
    else if(hitCount >= 2)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject); //this will destroy the gameObject that the component is attached to 
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems the OP's main problem was adding a delay to the events. Here is some updated code that addresses that problem:

```
bool waitingForFirstHit = true;
bool waitingForSecondHit  = false;
float timeDelay = 1.5f; 

void Update(){

    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.up, 5);

    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player" )
    {
        if (waitingForFirstHit) {

            ChangeColor();          
            waitingForFirstHit = false;
            waitingForSecondHit = true;
        }           
        else if(waitingForSecondHit && timeDelay < 0)
        {
            DestroyEnemy ();
        }
    }


    if(waitingForSecondHit)
    {
        timeDelay -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

void ChangeColor()
{
    rend.material.color = colorToTurnTo;
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hitInfo.point, Color.white);
}

void DestroyEnemy()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Here is a tutorial on using the Destroy function:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/destroy

And here is a link to the docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html

Cheers.

Comment: That caused the "if" and the "else if" statements to be called at the same time.

Comment: They're not being called at the same time. Things are just happening faster than you would like. I think the real issue you are having then is how to add a delay between events. I have added a second example showing how to set up a simple timer. A better way to do this is to use coroutines: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html But that might be a little bit more complicated than what you are looking for (I highly recommend learning about them, though). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But now towards the very bottom with the "void DestroyEnemy()" there's a red underline under "DestroyEnemy" and the error message says "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Comment: I fixed it.  I had to make the first letter lowercase.  I think that fixes it right?  Yes it works.  Now I need to figure out how to adjust the delay so you dont have to wait as long for the second jump, but im sure I can figure that part out.  Thanks for your help!